# Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found while only download as zip from online

Tags: php, xampp, zip

i have create zip achiever. i got

> Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found

error while only accessing download zip file on online.but in local host it's works fine. my local host version is 5.5.11 ,but  my online server version 5.4.33, i am battling with this, anyone can give me some ideas..
Thanks Advanced

Comment: are you using windows are linux?

Comment: please verify below answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the **ZipArchive** class to be present.
You need php's zip extension installed and enabled.

See this link http://php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php

Comment: i have upgrade my server version to 5.5.11, now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

PHP needs to have the `zip extension` installed to use ZipArchive class.

[Folow the Link to Install](http://php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php)